Help with Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
In "Calculus 5th Edition: Stewart, James", there is a question that involves evaluating the expression
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\,2\int_{0}^{\sqrt {r^2-x^2}}\sqrt {r^2-t^2}-x\,dt \;\;\;(1)$$
where $x,r>0.$ When I solve this using FTC 1, I end up with this being $0$. If I instead solve this integral, plug in the limits, and differentiate it, I end up with this
$$-2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
which is my desired equation. Obviously by FTC 1 this shouldn't be the case, however I am not sure where I am going wrong? Here are my steps in solving the initial equation.
By FTC 2, we know $(1)$ is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} (F(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})-F(0))$$
If we complete the differentiation and know that $F'=f$, where $f(t)=\sqrt{r^2-t^2}-x$, then
$$2(\sqrt{r^2-(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})^2}-x)\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$$
$$2(\sqrt{r^2-r^2+x^2}-x)\frac{-x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$$
$$2(x-x)\frac{-x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}=0$$
Thank you for the help!

Beware situations where the variable of the derivative features simultaneously in the bounds and in the integrand!

Hint: product rule
$$2\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_{0}^{\sqrt {r^2-x^2}}(\sqrt {r^2-t^2}-x)\mathrm dt =2 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\int_{0}^{\sqrt {r^2-x^2}}\sqrt {r^2-t^2}\,dt-2 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \left(x\int_{0}^{\sqrt {r^2-x^2}} \mathrm dt\right)$$

Wow I didn't see that. Thank you.

Very good way. +1

Leibniz rule for integrals:
$$\frac d{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt=f(x,a(x))a'(x)-f(x,b(x))b'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac\partial{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$$
İn OP's example,$\require{cancel}$
$$2\frac d{dx}\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}(\sqrt{r^2-t^2}-x)dt=2\left(\cancel{(x-x)(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})'}-\cancel{(r-x)\times0'}+\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}(-1)dt\right)=-2\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
